# Threading suppress thread until button press

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm

I have an app that I'm creating that is using MVVM and I need to split the work over to some threads and have no clue how and why it does not work what I'm doing. I need the UI to stay responsive but I want to deactivate a button the second I click it. my Code looks like this. The finished result is that I get the return from categoryconverter and the button goes back into isAvailable and the thread gets paused until next time they click the button? but right now its only the threading part that I cant get to work.

MainWindowViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Input;
using DataConverter.Checkers;
using DataConverter.Converters;
using DataConverter.Command;
using DataConverter.Objects;
using DataConverter.Threads; 

namespace DataConverter.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
       public List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
       public string path { get; set; }

       public bool runButtonWorks { get; set; }
       public string errorMessage { get; set; }
       public ICommand run { get; set; }
       public MainWindowViewModel()
       {
            runButtonWorks = true;

            ThreadOne th = new ThreadOne(); 

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(th.startProgram(path)));

            run = new RelayCommand(t1.Start);
       }
    }
}
```

ThreadOne:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DataConverter.Checkers;
using DataConverter.Converters;

namespace DataConverter.Threads
{
    class ThreadOne
    {
        public void startProgram(string path)
        {

        }


        private bool CategoryWorker(string path)
        {
            FileCheck checkFile = new FileCheck();
            CategoryConverter categoryConverter = new CategoryConverter();

            if (checkFile.checkFile(path))
            {
                runButtonWorks = false;
                categoryConverter.getCategoryList(path);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(th.startProgram(path)));
```

Creates the thread with `startProgram(...)` as its entry point. As soon as you start the thread, the code in that method is executed in the created thread. And since that method is empty, it does nothing at all.

Then there's the issue of notifying the UI thread that the worker thread is finished, and accepting its return value. There are different ways to accomplish this, depending on the UI platform you're working with.

If I were you I'd take a look at `System.Threading.Tasks` though, which has a cleaner API, especially for when you want a return value from your thread.